# Detect closed stream

Tags: perl

I have this simple program:

```
close STDIN;
exec("cat");
```

And the output:

```
cat: -: Bad file descriptor
cat: closing standard input: Bad file descriptor
```

I want to detect the same situation in Perl script I would `exec` in-place of `cat`.

So far I tried `fileno`, `tell` and `Scalar::Util::openhandle`, none of which produced good result

The solution should equally work for `STDERR`, `STDIN` and `STDOUT`

Comment: `print "closed" if eof(STDIN)`

Answer (score 0):

This will also work.

```
print "closed" if (tell(STDIN) == -1);
```

Comment: I found that calling  eof(STDIN) caused the program to wait for input if the STDIN was open.  Looking at the manual I found that this function actually reads a character and then ungetc s it, so isn't useful in an interactive context.

Cool question.  I learned some stuff figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

For POSIX compliant OS's you can use [select(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/select.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw[STDIN_FILENO];
use Errno qw[EBADF];

close STDIN unless @ARGV;

sub is_stdin_closed {
    vec(my $fdset = '', STDIN_FILENO, 1) = 1;
    my $nfound = select($fdset, undef, undef, 0);
    return ($nfound == -1 && $! == EBADF);
}

printf "is STDIN closed? %s\n", is_stdin_closed()? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: You might want to to retry the select call if ($nfound == -1 && $! == EINTR).